# Cannot convert from {int xyz} to int in C#

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework-core

I have run into the error message that cannot be surpassed by casting. How can I compare them?

```
var totalPrice =
                (some from joins here
                into g
                group g by new
                {
                    g.Id
                }
                into a
                select new
                {
                    RecordId = a.Key,
                    TotalAmount = a.Sum(e => e.Amount)
                });

foreach (var contract in query)
{
    foreach (var price in totalPrice)
    {
        if (price.RecordId == contract.ServiceRecordID)
        {
            
        }
    }
}
```

[image]
[image]

Comment: Why not just `group by g.Id`? Why did you wrap it in an object?

Comment: Looks like `RecordId`, aka `a.Key`, is an anonymous object `new { g.Id }`, but you're trying to compare that directly to an int. Either access that `Id` property, e.g. `price.RecordId.Id`, or do away with that anonymous object in the first place

Comment: nice font. (filler for 15 char min).

Comment: It's a nice font, but that IDE convention of adding hints to the code is not nice at all.

Comment: The hints themselves are not too bad (I see a lot of devs use plugins that do that) - its the vertical offset mismatch that bothers me!

Comment: The font is JetBrains Mono.  https://github.com/JetBrains/JetBrainsMono

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're grouping by an object with a single property, there is no need to do that - just group by the id itself, and then the `Key` will be just that int

```
var totalPrice =
            (some from joins here
            into g
            group g by g.Id
            into a
            select new
            {
                RecordId = a.Key,
                TotalAmount = a.Sum(e => e.Amount)
            });
```

Another alternative is this (but again, grouping by an object is unecessary):

```
var totalPrice =
            (some from joins here
            into g
            group g by new
            {
                g.Id
            }
            into a
            select new
            {
                RecordId = a.Key.Id, // read the Id
                TotalAmount = a.Sum(e => e.Amount)
            });
```

Comment: Thanks sir, my lack.